# Java negative counting?

Tags: java, arrays

i need a simple negative number counter in a basic bubble sort.. i have this code

```
public static void printArray(int[] a) {
    System.out.print("Tvoj niz je: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < a.length; ++k){
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println ( a[k] );

    }
    System.out.println();
}
public static void bubbleSort(int[] a) {
    int neg;
    int temp;       
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; ++j) {
    if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
    temp = a[j]; 
    a[j] = a[j + 1]; 
    a[j + 1] = temp;

  }
}



    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] a = {7, 4, 11, -3, 1, -2};
            bubbleSort(a);
            printArray(a);
```

now i need to have on output the number of negative numbers in array in this case number 2, because i have -3 and -2... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int negCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(a[i] < 0) {
        negCount++;
    }
}
```

negCount will hold the negative integers count.